# White label Nameservers (RDNS): IP and BIND Syntax Questions

Tags: networking, dns, centos, domain

Some questions regarding setting a RDNS on a DNS cluster using BIND/WHM/cPanel + WHM DNS Only.

**Objective**

Setting up a DNS Cluster of:

```
East US | Xen | CentOS 6.5 | with WHM/cPanel VPS | 2 IPv4 | Main server 
West US | Xen | CentOS 6.5 | with WHM DNS ONLY   | 2 IPv4 | Nameserver West
EU      | Xen | CentOS 6.5 | with WHM DNS ONLY   | 1 IPv4 | Nameserver Europe

5 IPv4 IPs
```

**Goal**

Making 3 white label (custom reverse DNS) geographically placed nameservers. One authoritative, secondary and tertiary.

--

**Questions about Nameserver IPs**

Is there another way to link 3 geographically different nameservers and use but 3 IPs using SNI (WHM/cPanel allows domains to share IPs in that fashion)?

IPv4 IPs are becoming more scarce. :/

--

**Questions about BIND zone syntax:**

For Reverse DNS of nameservers is it proper to identify the nameservers? For example:

```
1.168.192-rdns.ns1.my.custom.whitelabel.nameserver.tld.
1.168.192-rdns.ns2.my.custom.whitelabel.nameserver.tld.
1.168.192-rdns.ns3.my.custom.whitelabel.nameserver.tld.
```

Or reverse back to the hostname, instead?:

```
1.168.192.in-add.arpa-hostname1.domain.tld.
1.168.192.in-add.arpa-hostname2.domain.tld.
1.168.192.in-add.arpa-hostname3.domain.tld.
```

For PTR, and using the last octet, is it using IPs like this:

```
NS1 Nameserver IP: 192.168.1.0.100
NS2 Nameserver IP: 192.168.1.0.101
NS3 Nameserver IP: 192.168.1.0.102
```

In the reverse DNS zone like this?

```
0.1.168.192.in-add.arpa  IN  NS  ns1.my.custom.whitelabel.nameserver.tld.
0.1.168.192.in-add.arpa  IN  NS  ns2.my.custom.whitelabel.nameserver.tld.
0.1.168.192.in-add.arpa  IN  NS  ns3.my.custom.whitelabel.nameserver.tld.

100  IN  PTR  hostname1.domain.tld. ; main site hostname
101  IN  PTR  hostname2.domain.tld. ; second site hostname
102  IN  PTR  hostname3.domain.tld. ; third site hostname
```

PTR is still a tad confusing to me, as it's not a sub-domain pointer but acts like forwarding, instead.